# Does uploading a single player world preserve user stats/spawnpoint?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I have a single player world that I've invested a lot of time in and I want to upload it as a realm to keep it safe and to share it with my kids. I've uploaded the world several times now, but when I login I always spawn as if it's a new world (no armor, xp, etc) on an island I don't recognize (nowhere near the spawn point in my single player world).

I'm trying to understand what's happening. When you upload a world, does it erase user stats/inventories? Does the spawn point change? Or is my upload not succeeding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days and uploading my world at least half a dozen times, I had the idea of creating a new world, then trying the upload again. Apparently whatever was "stuck" got unstuck by this action, and not only was I able to upload my world, but my inventory and armor, etc., was intact.

So, if you have trouble uploading a world, try generating a new world, then re-uploading again.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, a realm can host three different worlds and a minigame. You can check as owner which world is active right now and see if that is the world which you uploaded.

Make sure that your uploaded world is the one which is active and all should be fine.

Comment: I think that might be true for desktop, but I don't think I've seen that option for pocket edition/xbox.